not able to extract specific data in sqlite table using flask python application
I am developing a flask app where I have a table named "TDS" inside sqlite database.

I want to access row wise specific data for example in column "Income_under_salary" in first row.
Code is .....
tds = TDS.query.all()
for td in tds:
    result = td.Income_under_salary
    print(result[0])

Here I am expecting to get answer "9", but I get "9 415244 38024" all three.
Type of "result" shows <class 'int'> <class 'int'> <class 'int'>
Since "result" is "int object" it is not iterable.
The HTML code:
{% for item in result %}
    <div> {{item}} </div>
{% endfor %}

The HTML also gives "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"
I am not sure even after mentioning index, why I am getting three answers?
Can someone help me to correct this code?

In result = td.Income_under_salary, result is an integer (9 for the first row). result[0] is meaningless because an integer doesn't have an element [0[, hence the error.

"Here I am expecting to get answer "9"" what makes you think that? And what do you expect for td in tds means?

@snakecharmerb you are correct I just want to figure out how I can access individual numbers in this case? In my database other table has single rows which are easily accessible but not this one.

@njzk2 when I am using result[0] I am expecting only "9" but all three values it shows. td is considered as an element in tds query.

And what do you expect for td in tds means?

by td means I want to get each item(or consider row)  inside tds query.

If you want result to contain array of all the cells, you should remove the for staement.
tds = TDS.query.all()
result = tds.Income_under_salary
print(result[0]) 
Now you can iterate this result variable in HTML.

Make result a list of the column value from each row:
result = [td.Income_under_salary for td in tds]

Then the Flask template will put each value in its own <div>.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
